# Get value of key in dict from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, class, dictionary

Let's say dict_lst = list of dict. I'm trying to return the value associated with the latest dict in dict_lst that has the argument k as a key. If k is not in any dict in dict_lst, we must raise KeyError. How would I do this?

```
def get_value(dict_lst, k):
   pass
```

EXAMPLE:

dict_lst = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'c':4, 'd':5, 'e':6}, {'e':7, 'f':8, 'g':9}]

d['c'] --> 4 (2nd dict with 'c' is found to be the latest dict)

d['y'] --> KeyError

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have the behaviour you are looking for:

```
def get_value(dict_lst, k):
    values = list()
    for dl in dict_lst:
        try:
            values.append(dl[k])
        except KeyError:
            pass
    if len(values) == 0:
        raise KeyError()
    return values[-1]


dict_lst = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'c':4, 'd':5, 'e':6}, {'e':7, 'f':8, 'g':9}]

get_values(dict_lst, k='c') # returns 4
get_values(dict_lst, k='y') # raises KeyError
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of the list so that the last element will be checked first

```py
dict_lst = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'c':4, 'd':5, 'e':6}, {'e':7, 'f':8, 'g':9}]
def get_value(dict_lst, k):
    for i in dict_lst[::-1]:
        if k in i.keys():
            return i.get(k)
    raise KeyError
print(get_value(dict_lst,'c')) #returns 4
print(get_value(dict_lst,'m')) #returns KeyError
```